# Fail uploading python package to artifactory if version already exists

Tags: python-3.x, github-actions, artifactory, setuptools

I have a Github repository for a python package, github-actions pushes the package to artifactory whenever a change to main has been made. I want to add something in github-actions that doesn't publish the package to artifactory if a version number alreaedy exists.

github actions code looks like:

```
      - name: Deploying Package
    env:
      PYRC: ${{ secrets.DI_PYPIRC }}
      PYCONF: ${{ secrets.DI_PY_PIP_CONF }}
    run: |
      echo "$PYRC" >> ~/.pypirc
      ls -a
      python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel upload -r local
```

PYRC and PYCONF are secrets that build the .pypirc and pip.conf file that are used to upload to artifactory and pip.conf is used to point the pip install to repositories to pull packages from.

Trying to add something here that would fail the build if setup.py has a version that is already available in artifactory. Is it possible to do through a github workflow?

Comment: Can you confirm if the user have override permission? If so, can you remove the override permission and test it out?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and how it did not work / what problem you faced.

Comment: @rethab I am not sure if this can be done through github actions, which is why i asked this question

Comment: @MuhammedKashif By override do you mean overwriting the existing packages? Yes, user can overwrite. Is there a setting in artifactory that lets me remove this functionality?

Comment: @qwerty, can you please elaborate on overwrite?  Is it at the package level where you make changes in the setup.py or at the Artifactory end? In Artifactory end, you can use the permissions target, kindly refer here https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Permissions

Comment: @MuhammedKashif overwrite is basically when I try to upload a package with the same version in setup.py file to artifactory it'll replace the package already in artifactory.

Comment: Yes exactly, this is getting overwritten in Artifactory because user has overwrite permission. Can you refer to the wiki I shared on permissions and check if user have "delete/overwrite" permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to do this:

1. Configure the Artifactory account used to upload to **not have delete/overwrite permissions** (you can read more about how permissions work here: [Artifactory Docs - Permissions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Permissions).

   In your GitHub Action then, it will recieve an error when it tries to upload, which fits your requirements.

   If interested, you could look more into [Artifactory Docs - Access Tokens](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Access+Tokens) as an approach, where you can create a token with specific permissions for specific repositories.
2. Write a script which checks via the Artifactory API whether that version exists and if it doesn't, then upload. You could use this endpoint [Artifactory API Docs - File Info](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FileInfo) probably to get this info.

   I would only do this approach if you don't have the ability to do the above, as the above would be the simpler/better approach.

Let us know how you go!